# Maven resource folder isn't created

Tags: maven

I'm using Eclipse Indigo with m2e plugin, and I've added to the build section of my `pom.xml` a `resources` tag. However the resource directory doesn't get created. I've also called Maven -> Update Project Configuration...

```
    <build>
        <finalName>...</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you create the maven project?  When I do `Create a new maven project`, and choose `Create a simple project (skip archetype selection`, I do get the default folders created (`src/main/java`, `src/main/resoures`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources`, along with the `pom.xml`).

Comment: Thanks Raughuram, I tried your way and resources folders got created. I've chosen a simple archetype, but I can't recall which.

Comment: @Raghuram I didn't have other answers, and your suggestion was good enough for me to solve the problem, can you provide a short answer that I will accept?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It appears that you may not have created the maven project correctly. Perhaps you may have chosen an archetype, which does not do this correctly.

One possible way (which worked for me) is as follows:

When I do Create a new maven project, and choose Create a simple project (skip archetype selection, I do get the default folders created (`src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources`, along with the `pom.xml`).

Comment: And don't have a typo ;-) - use src/main/resources instead of src/main/resoures

Answer (score 51):

If the resources folder itself doesn't exist create the folder under the folder main. Then Right click the project, go to Maven -> Update Project. It worked for me.

Comment: Adding a "resources" folder under "src/main" and "src/test" and then right-clicking the project and hitting Maven -> Update Project... worked for me.

Comment: @AdilHussain : You are a life saver bro, exactly what needed to complete the answer

Comment: @Thiruppathy , Super!!

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to creating a new project you could also have fixed the existing one by doing the following:

1. Do a non-destructive delete of the project from Eclipse i.e. do NOT check "Delete project contents on disk"
2. In the file system, remove the .settings/, .classpath, and .project files.
3. Also in the file system, add the resources folders under src/main and src/test.
4. In Eclipse, do an "Existing Maven Projects" import with the project's folder as the root.

Comment: Tricky, but indeed that did work. Just be careful if you try this method and perhaps backup your workspace first.

Answer (score 7):

This  tag `<resource>`

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

is not needed as this point because is the default resource folder  maven looks for. Just need to add this

> ```
> <resources>
>     <resource>
>        <directory>src/newDir/dir</directory>
>     </resource>
> </resources>
> ```

at your  pom.xml if you gonna use a  different  folder as a resource for your project.

Answer (score 5):

You can create the folders in your file system and after that, you can change the *.classpath* file in the root of the project, next to the *pom.xml*

Just add something like:

```
     <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
       <attributes>
         <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
     </classpathentry>
```

After create the folders and update the *.classpath* you only have to refresh (F5) in Eclipse.

PS: I don't know if this depends of your maven version, check if it is similar to the other "classpathentry" that you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting only one folder inside Java Resources(ie,src/main/java),and if you are looking for other folders(src/main/resoures, src/test/java) then do the following steps:[Dont forget to configure Server(like Tomcate)]

1)Right click on your project
2)Build path
3)congigure build path
4)Libraries
5)Add library
6)Server Runtime
7)then Select your server(In my case i have selected Tomcat)
8)Finish

Answer (score 1):

Every Maven Archetype has a different directory structure. See here the Maven website on the different available archetypes: https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/index.html

When choosing an Maven Archetype, you can follow the link above and click on the various archetypes and it will show you the directory structure that comes with each archetype. For example, the Maven Simple Project Archetype looks like this:
[Maven Simple Project Archetype directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFzbq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. ->
In Java Build Path tick both JRE System library and Maven Dependencies and click on Apply and close.

Answer (score 0):

My Maven project was created without src/main/resource and src/test/resource. I tried the below steps :

Create New Maven Project-->On "New Maven Project" screen -->Tick the "Create a simple project(skip archetype selection)"-->Provide the Project name-->Click Finish

Now you can see the resuorce folders created.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using intellij as your IDE, you can simply create the resources directory by right clicking the main folder in your project and attempt to make a new Directory, if you already don't have the resources Directory for your maven project, intellij has a suggestion for you to create it.

Answer (score -2):

I cleaned my project and solved my problem this way.

Menu > Project > Clean...